# What is the most efficient way to add a reflection to a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reflection, uiimageview

I just want the easiest way to make a reflection under a UIImageVies that is easily managable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Phil says, you can have a "reflected" UIImageView instance:

```
@interface ReflectedImageView : UIView 
{
@private
    UIImageView *_imageView;
    UIImageView *_imageReflectionView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;

@end
```

And then, in your implementation, something like this

```
@implementation ReflectedImageView

@dynamic image;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) 
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // This should be the size of your image:
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 290.0);

        _imageReflectionView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        _imageReflectionView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        _imageReflectionView.alpha = 0.4;
        _imageReflectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 290.0);
        [self addSubview:_imageReflectionView];

        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:_imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)newImage
{
    _imageView.image = newImage;
    _imageReflectionView.image = newImage;
}

- (UIImage *)image
{
    return _imageView.image;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [_imageView release];
    [_imageReflectionView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why are you changing the alpha of the reflected image, Then returning only one image?

Comment: I change the alpha to create a kind of "metallic" reflection effect :) As for the property getter, given that both image views receive the same image, returning either one of them is the same, and I chose to return the image from _imageView, but it's an arbitrary choice. Thanks for selecting my answer!

Comment: That's most of the way there. It doesn't include the "fade" effect, however.

Answer (score 20):

Just use the [sample code in the the iPhone SDK library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reflection/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008063)

**Update**: Link now updated to new location

Comment: Cool, that wasn't there last time I had to do this :-)

Comment: sorry, but URL is not valid by now

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reflection/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008063

Comment: Nice. Too bad the code to do this in that Apple's example is a set of 3 methods, rather than a drag-and-drop class. (and it doesn't create a correct scale image for retina display!). Will fix and hopefully I can share it after finish ;)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on how to generate reflections of any UI element or group of elements. The canned technique can be dropped into your project and is really easy to use. Source code and the article can be found at http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/08/no-fuss-reflections/

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way is to do it by hand in Photoshop! (seriously - if that's practical just do that).

Otherwise you'll need to make an inverted copy of the image (or at least the bottom half) to place below the real one, overlaid with a gradient from black (assuming your background is black) with alpha=1 to alpha=0.

If you need to place it over arbitrary backgrounds it's a little more complex as you'll have to apply the gradient from alpha = 0 to alpha = 1 to your inverted image.
I knocked up some code once to do it - will try and dig it out later when I get to my Mac, if nobody else has come up with anything sooner.

Comment: Er, how can the OP make reflections for other users' images? The idea is that his app has the reflections, like Cover Flow does.

Comment: you're making a lot of assumptions there, @JBRWilkinson