# UIImageview's reflection image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an imageview in my xib file. I have to create a reflection view in other UIimageview. So I have taken one UIimageview to place its reflection. it is around half of original image view.

Can anyone suggest me best way to do it. I have tried a lot of examples but not satisfied with any.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check out the reflection of UIImageView,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058801/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-add-a-reflection-to-a-uiimageview

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `CALayer` to do this (it would be more efficient than having a separate `UIImageView`).

Create a `CALayer`, add the image to it, set its transform property to scale(1,-1), and finally set its maskLayer to a `CAGradientLayer` that will go from opaque to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You try this :
 http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/88208-uiimage-reflection-tutorial.html

Comment: it is copied from here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058801/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-add-a-reflection-to-a-uiimageview